# Display the status bar on first click and make it disappear on second click

Tags: tkinter

I am creating a Notepad using Tkinter. I want to display Status Bar when I click on Status Bar and that Status Bar should disappear when I click it for the second time. How can I do this in Tkinter?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have some of your code to know what you have done by now but anyway here is something quite basic that might help you:

```
try: from tkinter import Tk,Button
except ImportError: from Tkinter import tk,Button

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        # stuff
        # self.statusbar is your statusbar (must be a widget)
        self.shown=False
        self.statusbar.bind('<Button-1>',self.clickstatusbar)
    def clickstaturbar(self,event=None):
        if self.shown: self.hidestatusbar()
        else: self.showstatusbar()
        self.shown=not self.shown
```